# Docker multiple output watcher commands

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Hi I currently have 1 container running my frontend application which includes a server side part written in nodeJS and a client side one written in React. To run the entire application I have to run 3 scripts:

- **CLIENT**: One for building and watching the client side code
- **SERVER**: One for building and wathing the server side part
- START: One to start the node application

I've just created a Docker container to build and start all my application but I need a way to run these 3 watcher commands with a separate log output. How may achieve my goal ?

Comment: Can you use ordinary host-based development environments for the two components; and then build a single Docker image that contains both parts for deployment, doing the build only in the Dockerfile?  What have you tried so far, and what problems are you encountering?

Comment: I need to find a way to print 3 different commands output